# SwiftUI (List & ForEach): Rotation of the device causes the current position in the List to be lost

Tags: list, dynamic, foreach, swiftui, rotation

With the SwiftUI code below (Xcode 12.2), after having **scrolled** through the list on a given row, the **rotation** of the device causes the **jump to other row**.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(10...90, id: \.self) { i in
            VStack {
                ForEach(1...9, id: \.self) { j in
                    Text("item \(i).\(j)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Please how to make the display of the current row not sensitive to the rotation of the device?

*This problem appears only when scrolling the list **between each rotation**.*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it has something to do with the List offset, I'm not exactly sure why. A solution could be to use a ScrollView instead, which seems more dynamic.

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        ForEach(10...90, id: \.self) { i in
            VStack {
                ForEach(1...9, id: \.self) { j in
                    Text("item \(i).\(j)")
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            Divider()
        }
    }
}
```